# How to initialize a variable once on the app.module using a service and use it later in other components?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a list of objects to be generated **once** in the application startup from a backend API using a service, the question is how to initialize that list and access it from the other components?

For example, in app.module.ts, I want something like:

```
    export class AppComponent {
  title = 'General Title';
  myListFromServiceApi:[DataType]; 
  }
```

How to call this in mycomponent.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
this.myListFromServiceApi= ??
}
```

**Edit**

I already have the service, but I want to avoid invoking the service every time the component added to a view, i.e call the service once in the lifetime of the application if that is possible, how can I achieve that?

Comment: If you want to access that list from multiple components I would keep it inside a service.

Comment: @robert Does that mean that you will invoke the service every time the component added to the DOM? I want that to be done only once.

Comment: Invoke only once to populate the member array "myListFromServiceApi" (http call) then inject the service into any component where you want to use the received array.

Comment: @robert That would be more than once!?

Comment: Just a sec I will prepare a stackblitz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the rx operator [`share`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html) that prevents a sideeffect (http request in your case) from being executed multiple times on subscription of multiple subscribers and return an observable that's piped through a `share` from a service, i.e. `DataTypeService`:

```
export class DataTypeService {

  dataTypes$: Observable<DataType>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.dataTypes$ = this.http.get('/api/datatypes').pipe(share());
  }

  getDataTypes() {
    return this.dataTypes$;
  }
}
```

In your components you could then inject the `DataTypeService`, subscribe to the observable returned by `getDataTypes()` and the request would only be executed once.

```
constructor(private dataTypeService: DataTypeService){
   this.dataTypeService.getDataTypes().subscribe(dataTypes => {
       this.myListFromServiceApi = dataTypes;
   })
}
```

If you only wanna work with those data types in your template you could also directly store the observable returned by `getDataTypes()` on your component and utilize the [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe

Comment: I am getting `Cannot find name 'share'` exception!

Comment: @TiyebM You have to import the operator like so `import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Answer (score 1):

See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4hztq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared.service.ts). Generally you have one sharedService. That will request the data once and store it as a local variable. Two other components (first and second) only Inject the service in the constructor and keep a reference to the member variable inside a sharedService. This way http call goes out only once. Invoked in:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedService.getDataOnce();
  }
```